# Is RESTEasy RegisterBuiltin.register necessary when using ClientResponse<T>

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I am developing a REST client using JBOSS app server and RESTEasy 2.3.6.  I've included the following line at the beginning of my code:

```
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Here's the rest of the snippet:

```
    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(host, port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userid,password));
    ClientExecutor executor = createAuthenticatingExecutor(httpclient, host, port);

    String uriTemplate = "http://myhost:8080/webapp/rest/MySearch";
    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(uriTemplate, executor);
    request.accept("application/json").queryParameter("query", searchArg);

    ClientResponse<SearchResponse> response = null;
    List<MyClass> values = null;
    try
    {
        response = request.get(SearchResponse.class);
        if (response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() != 200)
        {
            throw new Exception("REST GET failed");
        }
        SearchResponse searchResp = response.getEntity();
        values = searchResp.getValue();
    }
    catch (ClientResponseFailure e) 
    {
        log.error("REST call failed", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        response.releaseConnection();
    }

private ClientExecutor createAuthenticatingExecutor(DefaultHttpClient client, String server, int port)
{
    // Create AuthCache instance
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();

    // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(server, port);
    authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

    // Create ClientExecutor.
    ApacheHttpClient4Executor executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(client, localContext);
    return executor;
}
```

The above is a fairly simple client that employs the ClientRequest/ClientResponse<T> technique.  This is documented [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html). The above code does work (only left out some trivial variable declarations like host and port).  It is unclear to me from the JBOSS documentation as to whether I need to run RegisterBuiltin.register first.  If I remove the line completely - my code still functions.  Do I really need to include the register method call given the approach I have taken?  The Docs say I need to run this once per VM. Secondly, if I am required to call it, is it safe to call more than one time in the same VM?

NOTE: I do understand there are newer versions of RESTEasy for JBOSS, we are not there yet.